# Samba connection fails from OS X

Tags: linux, networking, mac-osx, samba, linux-networking

The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 and Samba 3.6.3. Windows users can mount their shares without problems, using the path `\\my_server.com\username` and account `\username`.

However, when I try to connect with OS X 10.10.5 native GUI client, authentication fails. The log looks like this:

```
2015/09/29 15:47:23.536252,  3] smbd/sesssetup.c:1107(reply_sesssetup_and_X_spnego)
  NativeOS=[Mac OS X 10.10] NativeLanMan=[SMBFS 3.0.2] PrimaryDomain=[]
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.536318,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlmssp_server.c:348(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[OSX_user] domain=[MY_SERVER] workstation=[workstation] len1=24 len2=260
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.536415,  3] auth/auth.c:219(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [MY_SERVER]\[OSX_user]@[workstation] with the new password interface
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.536469,  3] auth/auth.c:222(check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [MY_SERVER]\[OSX_user]@[workstation]
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.536638,  3] passdb/lookup_sid.c:1754(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for OSX_user
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.536825,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:392(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: NTLMv2 password check failed
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.536901,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:437(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: Lanman passwords NOT PERMITTED for user OSX_user
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.537053,  3] ../libcli/auth/ntlm_check.c:585(ntlm_password_check)
  ntlm_password_check: LM password, NT MD4 password in LM field and LMv2 failed for user OSX_user
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.537268,  2] auth/auth.c:319(check_ntlm_password)
   check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [OSX_user] -> [OSX_user] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_WRONG_PASSWORD
[2015/09/29 15:47:23.537346,  3] smbd/error.c:81(error_packet_set)
   error packet at smbd/sesssetup.c(124) cmd=115 (SMBsesssetupX) NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Any ideas why this happens? Do I need to enable NTLM for OS X users?

Comment: Did this just start happening recently, eg no-connect from OS X clients...?

Comment: @DavidW Not sure to be honest. I haven't checked for a while. I remember not having any problems some months ago.

Comment: OSX 10.10 introduced the SMB3 protocol, which I don't believe was yet introduced in Samba 3.6; I think it topped out at SMB2. Might be part of the problem as NTLM rides on SMB if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Following @DavidW's point about SMB versions: try connecting via Connect to Server (in the Finder's Go menu), and specifying the URL as `cifs://servername/` -- the "cifs" scheme will force it back to SMB version 1. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to force SMB version 2.